# SQL Server - Retrieve data with wrong encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding

I have a SQL Server which contains data with accents and sometimes with wrong encoding(Data with the character �).
I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve every line in this table which contains the character �

I have try the like function

```sql
SELECT 
BadField
FROM Table1
WHERE BadField LIKE N'%�%'
```

and

```sql
SELECT 
BadField
FROM Table1
WHERE BadField LIKE '%'+NCHAR(0xfffd)+ '%'
```

And with Regexp Code

```sql
SELECT 
BadField
FROM Table1
WHERE BadField '%[^A-Za-z0-9, ]%'
```

But i didn't manage to get the lines with the replacement character �.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a binary collation. This, at least, works for some made up valuse:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'abc'),(N'�'),(N'a�c'))V(S)
WHERE V.S COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE N'%�%';
```

Which returns both `'�'` and `'a�c'`.